# How to get Azure Resources Usage Details in azure pay as you go subscription for a specified start/end date

Tags: azure

I am trying to get the resource usage details for azure to date in my subscription.
I am using the following usage details API endpoint: [https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-03-31](https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2018-03-31)

Please note:- *For Scope filter I provided my subscription Id.*

When using the above endpoint I am able to retrieve two or three recent days' data, but I need data for a particular time period.

Note: I have Pay-As-You-Go Subscription(In an Organization)

I also tried using the above endpoints with start and end date filters as shown below:
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=usageStart](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BSubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=usageStart) eq `'2021-04-1' and usageEnd eq '2021-04-22'&api-version=2018-03-31`

Still getting the same output data. As I got 1000's of records and I can't post them all so I am posting few records:

```
{
      "id": "/subscriptions/000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/52ba141d-7920-7777-0772-0840af31fe59",
      "name": "52ba141d-7920-7777-0772-0840af31fe59",
      "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
      "tags": {
        "ms-resource-usage": "azure-cloud-shell"
      },
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105",
        "usageStart": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "usageEnd": "2021-04-25T23:59:59.0000000Z",
        "instanceId": "/subscriptions/00000000000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/csg10032000e24e2bd8",
        "instanceName": "csg10032000e24e2bd8",
        "instanceLocation": "IN Central",
        "meterId": "27d42441-b91e-4491-89fd-388c48477246",
        "usageQuantity": 0.000066,
        "pretaxCost": 0.00023537184,
        "currency": "INR",
        "isEstimated": false,
        "subscriptionGuid": "000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "subscriptionName": "Pay-As-You-Go",
        "product": "",
        "consumedService": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "partNumber": "",
        "resourceGuid": "27d42441-b91e-4491-89fd-388c48477246",
        "offerId": "MS-AZR-0003P",
        "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
        "meterDetails": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/df4de8b6-ea4e-5134-687f-f7dbd5288729",
      "name": "df4de8b6-ea4e-5134-687f-f7dbd5288729",
      "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
      "tags": {
        "ms-resource-usage": "azure-cloud-shell"
      },
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105",
        "usageStart": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "usageEnd": "2021-04-25T23:59:59.0000000Z",
        "instanceId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/csg10032000e398ade2",
        "instanceName": "csg10032000e398ade2",
        "instanceLocation": "IN Central",
        "meterId": "365a457f-78b3-4c98-8199-2c0459ed3e39",
        "usageQuantity": 0.10416,
        "pretaxCost": 0.49527944592,
        "currency": "INR",
        "isEstimated": false,
        "subscriptionGuid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "subscriptionName": "Pay-As-You-Go",
        "product": "",
        "consumedService": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "partNumber": "",
        "resourceGuid": "365a457f-78b3-4c98-8199-2c0459ed3e39",
        "offerId": "MS-AZR-0003P",
        "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
        "meterDetails": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/00000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/146d9ae9-dbf9-7c10-d557-f032dab22920",
      "name": "146d9ae9-dbf9-7c10-d557-f032dab22920",
      "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
      "tags": {
        "env": "Prod"
      },
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105",
        "usageStart": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "usageEnd": "2021-04-24T23:59:59.0000000Z",
        "instanceId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/Billing/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/quadbilling",
        "instanceName": "quadbilling",
        "instanceLocation": "IN South",
        "meterId": "b9e5e77c-a0b3-4a2c-9b8b-57fa54f31c52",
        "usageQuantity": 0.0152,
        "pretaxCost": 0.0003942272,
        "currency": "INR",
        "isEstimated": false,
        "subscriptionGuid": "000000000000000000000000000000",
        "subscriptionName": "Pay-As-You-Go",
        "product": "",
        "consumedService": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "partNumber": "",
        "resourceGuid": "b9e5e77c-a0b3-4a2c-9b8b-57fa54f31c52",
        "offerId": "MS-AZR-0003P",
        "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
        "meterDetails": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/89b4815b-cc83-dc58-0159-c5c7b998c847",
      "name": "89b4815b-cc83-dc58-0159-c5c7b998c847",
      "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
      "tags": null,
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/00000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105",
        "usageStart": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "usageEnd": "2021-04-24T23:59:59.0000000Z",
        "instanceId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/QmigratorVmCreate-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/myVMPublicIP",
        "instanceName": "myVMPublicIP",
        "instanceLocation": "IN Central",
        "meterId": "26ce34b7-67b3-480d-9d1b-54a7fb80f67a",
        "usageQuantity": 24,
        "pretaxCost": 6.224688,
        "currency": "INR",
        "isEstimated": false,
        "subscriptionGuid": "00000000000000000000000000000",
        "subscriptionName": "Pay-As-You-Go",
        "product": "",
        "consumedService": "Microsoft.Network",
        "partNumber": "",
        "resourceGuid": "26ce34b7-67b3-480d-9d1b-54a7fb80f67a",
        "offerId": "MS-AZR-0003P",
        "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
        "meterDetails": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/000000000000000000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/3c524b3c-03bc-5de5-3dc4-44dfc9713677",
      "name": "3c524b3c-03bc-5de5-3dc4-44dfc9713677",
      "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
      "tags": {
        "ms-resource-usage": "azure-cloud-shell"
      },
      "properties": {
        "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/00000000000000000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/202105",
        "usageStart": "2021-04-17T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "usageEnd": "2021-04-17T23:59:59.0000000Z",
        "instanceId": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/csg100320010984c65f",
        "instanceName": "csg100320010984c65f",
        "instanceLocation": "IN Central",
        "meterId": "365a457f-78b3-4c98-8199-2c0459ed3e39",
        "usageQuantity": 0.166656,
        "pretaxCost": 0.792447113472,
        "currency": "INR",
        "isEstimated": false,
        "subscriptionGuid": "000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "subscriptionName": "Pay-As-You-Go",
        "product": "",
        "consumedService": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "partNumber": "",
        "resourceGuid": "365a457f-78b3-4c98-8199-2c0459ed3e39",
        "offerId": "MS-AZR-0003P",
        "chargesBilledSeparately": false,
        "meterDetails": null
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `particular time period`? Do you want to specify start/end date time for which you want to retrieve the usage data?

Comment: Yes I want data from particular start date to end date, and I tried giving start date and end date filters in URL but it is not working.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the filter you used. Also, include the result you're getting.

Comment: Updated the question and included the filters and also the data I am getting